# Configuring CORS for WSO2 API Manager JWT Grant token endpoint

Tags: cors, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a browser application that calls WSO2 API Manager [JWT Grant](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/JWT+Grant) endpoint to exchange a JWT for an access token.

The endpoint invoked from Javascript is `https://WSO2APIM/oauth2/token`

The problem is this call is blocked by the browser because of the CORS restriction:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://WSO2APIM/oauth2/token/. (Reason: CORS
>   header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

How can I configure the CORS permission for this endpoint?

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable cors by adding cors hanlder to the token endpoint

```
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35306629/1110305